# Calculus 3 Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

Find the volume of the solid bounded by $z=4x^2+4y^2, z=0, x^2+y^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=2$.

**What I know:**
I know that when I draw the graph I will get two paraboloids giving me a radius of $1$ and $2$,$\theta= 2\pi$, and $z= 0$ to $4r^2$.

I keep getting a large number like $30\pi$ when the answer should $6\pi$.

Can anyone help me ? 
Thanks

Comment: Use cylindrical coordinates, and the radius is $\sqrt2$ not $2$

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us how you get a large number like $30\pi?$

Comment: I got 30pi by having theta to be 0 to 2pi, radius: 1 to 2 and z: 0 to 4r^2 and integrating 1*r dzdrdθ

Comment: It can also be worked as a solid of revolution of a region in the $xz$ plane bounded by graphs of $z=0$, $z=4x^2$, $x=1$ and $x=\sqrt{2}$ using the cylindrical shell method. Gives answer of $V=6\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Find the volume of the solid of revolution formed by revolving about the $x$ axis the figure in the $xz$-plane bounded by the graphs of $z=0$, $z=4x^2$, $x=1$ and $x=\sqrt{2}$.

$$ V=\int_1^{\sqrt{2}}2\pi rh\,dx$$

where $r=x$ and $h=4x^2$.

$$ V=2\pi\int_1^{\sqrt{2}}4x^3\,dx=2\pi[x^4]_1^{\sqrt{2}}=6\pi $$

[image: Solid of revolution]